# No internet sound in windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have sound on my laptop everywhere except the internet.  I once used command in the command prompt that started with snd but I don't remember the rest.  It pulled up a screen with different volumes, one of which was the internet.  Mine was turned off.  It has done this again and I don't remember the command to enter to get the pop-up screen.

Answer (score 0):

The 'volume mixer' is a right-click on the speaker symbol near the clock and then 'Open volume mixer' in the menu.  When the mixer is open, check that the volume for Chrome (or Edge or Firefox or whatever) is turned up.

[image: Opening volume mixer on Windows 10]